# exchanging data between web application and individual process

Tags: architecture

SERVER SIDE
a 24-hour running linux program (say A): processes and holds data
web server: handles web request

CLIENT SIDE(browser)
request http://mydomain.com/getdata to get the data

for each web request, the web server(or web application running on it) should ask program A for the latest data

is there any framework can help me build such a architecture quickly?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The [LAMP Stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) will give you what you want.  LAMP = Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP.

It is widely used for applications that match your needs, and is supported by a large active community.

You should have no problem finding good tutorials that help you get the platform established, once that's done all you need to do is go looking for tutorials on how to develop PHP websites that include database access.

With PHP there's lots of open source Content Management Systems that might give you what you need (such as [Drupal](http://drupal.org/)) and in terms of PHP frameworks there's stuff like the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/).